# Creating vector of move-constructed objects

Tags: c++, move, stdvector, unique-ptr, emplace

I have a class which contains a constructor which moves an object during its construction:

```
class SomeClass
{
private:
    const std::unique_ptr<Base> foo;

public:
    template <typename T>
    inline explicit SomeClass(T&& derived) noexcept
     : foo(std::make_unique<T>(derived))
    {
        static_assert(std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value);
    }
};
```

The an object of the class can be constructed without issue when I require only a single instance:

```
class Derived : public Base
{
    // ...
};

Derived bar(...);
SomeClass baz(std::move(bar));

// Or

SomeClass baz(Derived(...));
```

However I am unable to emplace (or push) any objects of type SomeClass to a `std::vector<SomeClass>`.

```
std::vector<SomeClass> vec;

Derived bar(...);
vec.emplace_back(std::move(bar)); // Does not work.

vec.emplace_back(Derived(...));   // Does not work.
```

Please could you explain why objects can not be emplaced? I thought that the perfect forwarding that `emplace_back` used would allow construction of an instance of `SomeClass` inplace in the same way that a single instance could be constructed.

Please could you also explain how things might be modified to allow construction of a `std::vector<SomeClass>`?

My guess is that as constructor arguments are passed by move, then they are not being forwarded all the way to the constructor within the `emplace_back` method.

Comment: That's not a move constructor, and in no way is it `noexcept`.

Comment: `SomeClass` has default constructors.

Comment: It isn't a move constructor in the sense that it doesn't construct a new instance by moving another pre-existing one, but it moves the given arguments during the constructor. I haven't seen any warnings regarding the noexcept.

Comment: @DeanSeo Does the presence of default constructors prevent emplace in some way?

Comment: @DeanSeo Marking special constructor methods as delete does not seem to change anything, but I'm not sure why it would?

Comment: So now re-looking at it, I figured out that you renamed `Detector` with `SomeClass` but forgot to do it on the name of the constructor which looks like a member function. But still, it takes a *forwarding* reference, which is not a move constructor.

Comment: Thanks, I've edited to fix the typo and to clarify what I mean by 'only move constructor'.

Comment: You need to also remove the `const` from the input parameter.  You can't *move* data using an rvalue reference to a **const** object, that would prevent you from being able to modify that object to make it relinquish ownership of its data

Comment: @RemyLebeau, thanks for the catch and explaining it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`std::vector::emplace_back`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/emplace_back) imposes the following requirements on `value_type`:

> **Type requirements**
>
> -`T` (the container's element type) must meet the requirements of `MoveInsertable` and `EmplaceConstructible`.

A `const` member of a class implicitly deletes move constructor, i.e. `SomeClass` is not `MoveInsertable` because of `const std::unique_ptr<Base> foo`.

Solution: remove `const` from `foo`.

```
struct Base {};
struct Derived : public Base {};

class SomeClass
{
private:
    std::unique_ptr<Base> foo;

public:
    template <typename T>
    inline explicit SomeClass(T&& derived)
        noexcept(std::is_nothrow_constructible_v<decltype(foo), T&&>) // (1)
     : foo(std::make_unique<T>(std::forward<T>(derived))) // (2)
    {
        static_assert(std::is_base_of<Base, T>::value);
    }
};

int main()
{
    std::vector<SomeClass> vec;

    Derived bar{};
    vec.emplace_back(std::move(bar));

    vec.emplace_back(Derived{}); 
}
```

[Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/84c6b762f7607878).

As a side note, I would suggest to make `noexcept` conditional depending on `std::is_nothrow_constructible` (1) and pass `std::forward<T>(derived)` to `std::make_unique` to utilise forwarding reference (2).

Comment: Thank you. The error message regarding not being move-insertable because of const is usually more obvious, but I guess the templating messages obscured it. Thanks for the tip about using std::forward too!